# Binding a single event handler to multiple events with jQuery

Tags: jquery, events

I have the following div with different functions for onblur, onmousedown, onmouseup, and onfocus.. I want to minimize the code and have only one function call inside div for all the function states. I want to do this with jquery So in other words. I want to create a function called functionAll and put all of function1 to function 4 with it's mouse state inside, then just use functionAll inside the Div. How can I do something like this?

```
<div contentEditable="true"
     onblur="function1();"
     onmousedown="return function2(event);"
     onmouseup="function3();"
     onfocus="function4();">
    test test
</div>
```

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You should put an id on the div, say "test", then:

```
$('#test').bind('blur mousedown mouseup focus', function (e) {
    // This is your combined function
    // Inside here you can use e.type to find out whether it was a
    // "blur", "mousedown", "mouseup", etc...
});
```

The HTML will look like:

```
<div id="test" contentEditable="true">
    test test
</div>
```

Comment: @Box9 Somehow I missed that in the docs, that was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!