# jQuery function in two events

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events

I have this code:

```
$('#email').keyup(function() {
            if(true || false)) {

            } else {

            }
        });
```

I need include this function also in blur event.

I've tried to create a jquery function but I could not. Somebody give me a light.

Comment: I really hope you don't have `if(true || false) {` in your actual code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Binding a single event handler to multiple events with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4710219/binding-a-single-event-handler-to-multiple-events-with-jquery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a separate function as follows

```
function funcName(){
//Your code
}
```

Now,use jQuery on

```
 $("#email").on("keyup",funcName);
 $("#email").on("blur",funcName);
```

For reference,check

http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 5):

You can do this -

```
$('#email').on('keyup blur',function() {
```

- http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 2):

Use the `on` method to attach multiple events, which are specified in the first argument passed to the function.

```
$('#email').on('keyup blur', function() {
    if(true || false) {  //there was an extra ) here

    } else {

    }
});
```

**Working Example** http://jsfiddle.net/nv39M/

One thing to be aware of, the `keyup` event is going to fire prior to the `blur` event firing.

Comment: @user2465422 Glad I can help, let me know if you have any further questions.  Good Luck!

Comment: I'm having trouble with the event change, don't work. when I click a value that firefox saves the form (one that has already been used), it does not perform validation. How to do it?

Answer (score 1):

There are (at least) two ways you could achieve this.

1. Specify multiple, space separated events as the first argument:

   ```
   $('#email').on('keyup blur',function() {
       // your logic
   });
   ```
2. Use a named function:

   ```
   function yourFunction() {
       // your logic
   }

   $('#email').on('keyup', yourFunction);
   $('#email').on('blur', yourFunction);
   ```

Option 1 is probably the best choice assuming you don't want to use the function anywhere else, and that you want to bind the event handlers at the same time. If, however, you wanted to bind the `blur` event at a later point (perhaps in response to another event), or to a different element, then the named function method would be the best choice.